# Beginner Question: Navigation Based Application iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder

Okay, so I am a beginner at Cocoa and I've decided to try to make my first app. I went into Xcode and made a new app, I chose Navigation Based Application because it was the first one on the list.I need a tutorial that teaches me how to make a simple Navigation Based Application for the iPhone. I want it to be able to allow me to control what shows up when I click the '+'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see how navigation-based applications work, it would be suggestible to choose view-based application instead and work from there.

I would also suggest watching: [Navigation & Tab Bar Controllers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-FK1TrpUng)

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty awesome.